# Python re: how to lowercase some words

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a text string

```
"StringText someText Wwwwww SomeOtherText OtherText SOMETextMore etc etc etc"
```

and need to lowercase all words starting from "S" or "s". But not other words. Pls advive with re code (better using re, not plain loop to replace chars, pls). Py2x.

Comment: We're not here to do your work for you. You need to try *something*.

Comment: Right, but i didn't know about all `sub` features.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: @Henry, no, I just learn Py and want a start point with re.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wanted solution using regex, here you are:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "StringText someText Wwwwww SomeOtherText OtherText SOMETextMore etc etc etc"
>>> def replacement(match):
...   return match.group(1).lower()
>>> re.sub(r'([sS]\w+)', replacement, s)
'stringtext sometext Wwwwww someothertext OtherText sometextmore etc etc etc'
```

Comment: +1. Just a rookie Regex question, though - Is your regex similar to this one -- `r'\b([Ss].*?)\b'`? Thanks. :)

Comment: Why do you have a "+" after `[sS]`?  The same can be accomplished with `re.sub(r'([sS]\w+)', replacement, s)`.

Comment: Yes, in this case it will produce the same result. May be yours is better in terms that you are explicitly using `\b` as word boundaries.

Comment: @SukritKalra your regex will match `S`, unlike alecxe's one..

Comment: @deathApril : Replacing the `*` with a `+` should do the trick though right?

Comment: @deathApril nice observation, thank you. I think this is not that a difference in this case..though we should know more about the text.. :)

Comment: ..it depends if you want to change `S` to `s` or not..

Comment: +1 Nice solution. You can get rid of the capturing group as well, and then just use `.group()` along with `[sS]\w+`.

Comment: @arshajii truly noted! thank you! I've just started with saving groups and was happy when got it worked :)